# Is there a corresponding Hahn decomposition theorem for the real-valued Radon measures?

Tags: measure-theory, integration, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Hello,

As we know that a signed measure $\mu$ on $R$ can be decomposed to the positive part $\mu_+$ and negative one $\mu_-$ by [the Hahn decomposition theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem)

My question is whether each real-valued Radon measure $\nu$ on $R$ can be decomposed by the positive and negative parts? I think it is true. If the proof is long, Where can I find a reference?

Here is my motivation: the real-valued Radon measure on $R$ seems more general than the signed measure. For example, on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure), you can find the example $sin(x)d x$ which is a real-valued Radon measure but not a signed measure. By this reason, I would like to work under the real-valued radon measure. However, I am not an expert on measure theory, especially on Radon measure stuff.

Thank you very much!

Anand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd take the view that a real-valued Radon measure "really is" a continuous linear functional $\Lambda:C_{00}(X,\mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb R$.  Here $X$ is a locally compact space, and $C_{00}(X,\mathbb R)$ is the collection of compactly supported continuous real valued functions on $X$.  By "continuous", we mean that for each compact $K\subseteq X$, there is a constant $c>0$ such that
$$ |\Lambda(f)| \leq c \|f\|_\infty $$
for all continuous $f$ supported in $K$.  (For example, with $\Lambda$ given by integrating against $\sin(x) \ dx$, we can take $c$ to be the Lebesgue measure of $K$).

So you could just work abstractly with such linear functionals.  (This is going to be a sketch, but if you've done a course on abstract integration, nothing should be too great a surprise).  Then you do the usual trick: define
$$ \Lambda_+(f) = \sup\{ \Lambda(g) : 0\leq g\leq f \} $$
for all $f\in C_{00}(X,\mathbb R)$ which are (pointwise) positive.  The supremum is positive (take $g=0$) and finite because $\Lambda$ is continuous.
Notice that $\Lambda_+$ is positive homogeneous, and clearly $\Lambda_+(f_1) + \Lambda_+(f_2) \leq \Lambda_+(f_1+f_2)$.  Conversely, if $0 \leq g \leq f_1+f_2$, then let $g_1=\min(g,f_1)$ and $g_2=g-g_1$, so $0\leq g_1\leq f_1$, $0\leq g_2\leq g_2$, and $\Lambda(g) = \Lambda(g_1)+\Lambda(g_2)$.  It follows that $\Lambda_+$ is additive.

Then extend $\Lambda_+$ to all of $C_{00}(X,\mathbb R)$ by $\Lambda_+(f) = \Lambda_+(f_+) - \Lambda_+(f_-)$.  That $\Lambda_+$ is linear will follow from *exactly* the same proof which shows that the Lebesgue integral is linear (having first defined it for positive functions) from pretty much any course on integration.

Then define $\Lambda_-(f) = \Lambda_+(f) - \Lambda(f)$, so
$$ \Lambda_-(f) = \sup\{ \Lambda(h) : -f\leq h\leq 0 \}\geq 0 $$
(set $h=g-f$).  So $\Lambda_+$ and $\Lambda_-$ are *positive* linear functionals on $C_{00}(X,\mathbb R)$ and are hence given by positive Radon measures.

I don't know a self-contained reference-- as I say, I was exposed to these ideas in courses on integration theory, and basic functional analysis.  I like Rudin's book "Real and complex analysis" for the basics on positive Radon measures.

Comment: I think Lang treats this stuff in his "real and functional analysis" book

Comment: @Matthew Daws, thank you so much for such detailed answer. It really helps! I still have a doubt. I think $C_{00}(X;R)$ is still a locally convex topology space with semi-norms depending on compact sets?  

Comment: @Orbicular, thank you. I will have a look of Lang's book. It is a shame that I have never opened his books. :-)

Comment: @Anand, yes, the notion of continuity is that given by the semi-norms-- this is explained, vaguely, in the Wikipedia article which you link to.

Comment: @Matthew Daws, yes, I see. Thanks a lot! :-)


Answer (score 2):

Try Jordan decomposition.  A signed measure $\mu$ has *positive* and *negative* sets, unique up to measure zero.  So do this on each of $[n,n+1)$, then take union, to get positive and negative sets for your signed Radon measure.

Comment: Thanks Professor Gerald Edgar. I happened to come across your book when I looked through measure theory books in our library yesterday. I think it works as you suggested. But we might need a little more care since we need to deal with the restriction of a distribution on a set. This restriction is multiplication of distribution by a indicator function which we couldn't pass to the test function side. But since we only care about zero order distributions, it saves us. Thanks!